# error when add new UDT type field to Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

When I try to add a new UDT type field to my cassandra table, I executed commands like:

```
CREATE TYPE price(
    micros bigint,
    currency_code varchar,
    formatted_amount varchar
);
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD price frozen;
```

But I got an exception:

```
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:38 missing EOF at '<' (...table metadata_m add price type [<]price...)">
```

So how to solve this problem?

I am using c* 2.1.2, cql3.2.0, cqlsh 5.0.1.

Comment: A prior edit added the exception text.  I would have updated it, but I didn't want to just assume that you saw the same exception that I did.  If that is not the same exception you saw, please edit and update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it usually helps if you provide the exception you received in your question.  Fortunately for you, my sandbox has the exact same C* specs you mentioned above, so I did manage to see this exception when pasting in your code:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TYPE price( micros bigint, currency_code varchar, formatted_amount varchar ); 
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD price frozen;
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="Failed parsing statement: [ALTER TABLE some_data ADD price frozen;] reason: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1">
```

I deducted that it was because you specified the type `price`, but did not actually provide a name for the column.  Also, `frozen` needs to be used with the type following it in angle brackets.  This worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD myprice frozen<price>;
```